# get_theme_file_uri function not showing background image inside data-setbg in html

Tags: images

I am stuck with background image not showing using get_theme_file_uri() function inside data-setbg

frontpage.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <!-- Hero Section Begin -->
    <section class="hero">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div class="hero__categories">
                        <div class="hero__categories__all">
                            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                            <span>All departments</span>
                        </div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Fresh Meat</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Vegetables</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Fruit & Nut Gifts</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Fresh Berries</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Ocean Foods</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Butter & Eggs</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Fastfood</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Fresh Onion</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Papayaya & Crisps</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Oatmeal</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Fresh Bananas</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-9">
                    <div class="hero__search">
                        <div class="hero__search__form">
                            <form action="#">
                                <div class="hero__search__categories">
                                    All Categories
                                    <span class="arrow_carrot-down"></span>
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="What do yo u need?">
                                <button type="submit" class="site-btn">SEARCH</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="hero__search__phone">
                            <div class="hero__search__phone__icon">
                                <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="hero__search__phone__text">
                                <h5>+65 11.188.888</h5>
                                <span>support 24/7 time</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hero__item set-bg" data-setbg="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('img/hero/banner.jpg'); ?>">
                        <div class="hero__text">
                            <span>FRUIT FRESH</span>
                            <h2>Vegetable <br />100% Organic</h2>
                            <p>Free Pickup and Delivery Available</p>
                            <a href="#" class="primary-btn">SHOP NOW</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Hero Section End -->

    <!-- Categories Section Begin -->
    <section class="categories">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="categories__slider owl-carousel">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <div class="categories__item set-bg" data-setbg="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('img/categories/cat-1.jpg'); ?>">
                            <h5><a href="#">Fresh Fruit</a></h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <div class="categories__item set-bg" data-setbg="img/categories/cat-2.jpg">
                            <h5><a href="#">Dried Fruit</a></h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <div class="categories__item set-bg" data-setbg="img/categories/cat-3.jpg">
                            <h5><a href="#">Vegetables</a></h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <div class="categories__item set-bg" data-setbg="img/categories/cat-4.jpg">
                            <h5><a href="#">drink fruits</a></h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <div class="categories__item set-bg" data-setbg="img/categories/cat-5.jpg">
                            <h5><a href="#">drink fruits</a></h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Categories Section End -->

    <!-- Featured Section Begin -->
    <section class="featured spad">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="section-title">
                        <h2>Featured Product</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="featured__controls">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="active" data-filter="*">All</li>
                            <li data-filter=".oranges">Oranges</li>
                            <li data-filter=".fresh-meat">Fresh Meat</li>
                            <li data-filter=".vegetables">Vegetables</li>
                            <li data-filter=".fastfood">Fastfood</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row featured__filter">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mix oranges fresh-meat">
                    <div class="featured__item">
                        <div class="featured__item__pic set-bg" data-setbg="img/featured/feature-1.jpg">
                            <ul class="featured__item__pic__hover">
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-retweet"></i></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="featured__item__text">
                            <h6><a href="#">Crab Pool Security</a></h6>
                            <h5>$30.00</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mix vegetables fastfood">
                    <div class="featured__item">
                        <div class="featured__item__pic set-bg" data-setbg="img/featured/feature-2.jpg">
                            <ul class="featured__item__pic__hover">
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-retweet"></i></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="featured__item__text">
                            <h6><a href="#">Crab Pool Security</a></h6>
                            <h5>$30.00</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mix vegetables fresh-meat">
                    <div class="featured__item">
                        <div class="featured__item__pic set-bg" data-setbg="img/featured/feature-3.jpg">
                            <ul class="featured__item__pic__hover">
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-retweet"></i></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="featured__item__text">
                            <h6><a href="#">Crab Pool Security</a></h6>
                            <h5>$30.00</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mix fastfood oranges">
                    <div class="featured__item">
                        <div class="featured__item__pic set-bg" data-setbg="img/featured/feature-4.jpg">
                            <ul class="featured__item__pic__hover">
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-retweet"></i></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="featured__item__text">
                            <h6><a href="#">Crab Pool Security</a></h6>
                            <h5>$30.00</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mix fresh-meat vegetables">
                    <div class="featured__item">
                        <div class="featured__item__pic set-bg" data-setbg="img/featured/feature-5.jpg">
                            <ul class="featured__item__pic__hover">
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-retweet"></i></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="featured__item__text">
                            <h6><a href="#">Crab Pool Security</a></h6>
                            <h5>$30.00</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mix oranges fastfood">
                    <div class="featured__item">
                        <div class="featured__item__pic set-bg" data-setbg="img/featured/feature-6.jpg">
                            <ul class="featured__item__pic__hover">
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-retweet"></i></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="featured__item__text">
                            <h6><a href="#">Crab Pool Security</a></h6>
                            <h5>$30.00</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mix fresh-meat vegetables">
                    <div class="featured__item">
                        <div class="featured__item__pic set-bg" data-setbg="img/featured/feature-7.jpg">
                            <ul class="featured__item__pic__hover">
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-retweet"></i></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="featured__item__text">
                            <h6><a href="#">Crab Pool Security</a></h6>
                            <h5>$30.00</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mix fastfood vegetables">
                    <div class="featured__item">
                        <div class="featured__item__pic set-bg" data-setbg="img/featured/feature-8.jpg">
                            <ul class="featured__item__pic__hover">
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-retweet"></i></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="featured__item__text">
                            <h6><a href="#">Crab Pool Security</a></h6>
                            <h5>$30.00</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Featured Section End -->

    <!-- Banner Begin -->
    <div class="banner">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="banner__pic">
                        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/banner/banner-1.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="banner__pic">
                        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/banner/banner-2.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Banner End -->

    <!-- Latest Product Section Begin -->
    <section class="latest-product spad">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                    <div class="latest-product__text">
                        <h4>Latest Products</h4>
                        <div class="latest-product__slider owl-carousel">
                            <div class="latest-prdouct__slider__item">
                                <a href="#" class="latest-product__item">
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__pic">
                                        <img src="img/latest-product/lp-1.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__text">
                                        <h6>Crab Pool Security</h6>
                                        <span>$30.00</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="latest-product__item">
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__pic">
                                        <img src="img/latest-product/lp-2.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__text">
                                        <h6>Crab Pool Security</h6>
                                        <span>$30.00</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="latest-product__item">
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__pic">
                                        <img src="img/latest-product/lp-3.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__text">
                                        <h6>Crab Pool Security</h6>
                                        <span>$30.00</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="latest-prdouct__slider__item">
                                <a href="#" class="latest-product__item">
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__pic">
                                        <img src="img/latest-product/lp-1.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__text">
                                        <h6>Crab Pool Security</h6>
                                        <span>$30.00</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="latest-product__item">
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__pic">
                                        <img src="img/latest-product/lp-2.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__text">
                                        <h6>Crab Pool Security</h6>
                                        <span>$30.00</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="latest-product__item">
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__pic">
                                        <img src="img/latest-product/lp-3.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__text">
                                        <h6>Crab Pool Security</h6>
                                        <span>$30.00</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                    <div class="latest-product__text">
                        <h4>Top Rated Products</h4>
                        <div class="latest-product__slider owl-carousel">
                            <div class="latest-prdouct__slider__item">
                                <a href="#" class="latest-product__item">
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__pic">
                                        <img src="img/latest-product/lp-1.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__text">
                                        <h6>Crab Pool Security</h6>
                                        <span>$30.00</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="latest-product__item">
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__pic">
                                        <img src="img/latest-product/lp-2.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__text">
                                        <h6>Crab Pool Security</h6>
                                        <span>$30.00</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="latest-product__item">
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__pic">
                                        <img src="img/latest-product/lp-3.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__text">
                                        <h6>Crab Pool Security</h6>
                                        <span>$30.00</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="latest-prdouct__slider__item">
                                <a href="#" class="latest-product__item">
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__pic">
                                        <img src="img/latest-product/lp-1.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__text">
                                        <h6>Crab Pool Security</h6>
                                        <span>$30.00</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="latest-product__item">
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__pic">
                                        <img src="img/latest-product/lp-2.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__text">
                                        <h6>Crab Pool Security</h6>
                                        <span>$30.00</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="latest-product__item">
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__pic">
                                        <img src="img/latest-product/lp-3.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__text">
                                        <h6>Crab Pool Security</h6>
                                        <span>$30.00</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                    <div class="latest-product__text">
                        <h4>Review Products</h4>
                        <div class="latest-product__slider owl-carousel">
                            <div class="latest-prdouct__slider__item">
                                <a href="#" class="latest-product__item">
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__pic">
                                        <img src="img/latest-product/lp-1.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__text">
                                        <h6>Crab Pool Security</h6>
                                        <span>$30.00</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="latest-product__item">
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__pic">
                                        <img src="img/latest-product/lp-2.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__text">
                                        <h6>Crab Pool Security</h6>
                                        <span>$30.00</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="latest-product__item">
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__pic">
                                        <img src="img/latest-product/lp-3.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__text">
                                        <h6>Crab Pool Security</h6>
                                        <span>$30.00</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="latest-prdouct__slider__item">
                                <a href="#" class="latest-product__item">
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__pic">
                                        <img src="img/latest-product/lp-1.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__text">
                                        <h6>Crab Pool Security</h6>
                                        <span>$30.00</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="latest-product__item">
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__pic">
                                        <img src="img/latest-product/lp-2.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__text">
                                        <h6>Crab Pool Security</h6>
                                        <span>$30.00</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="latest-product__item">
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__pic">
                                        <img src="img/latest-product/lp-3.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="latest-product__item__text">
                                        <h6>Crab Pool Security</h6>
                                        <span>$30.00</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Latest Product Section End -->

    <!-- Blog Section Begin -->
    <section class="from-blog spad">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="section-title from-blog__title">
                        <h2>From The Blog</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="blog__item">
                        <div class="blog__item__pic">
                            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/blog/blog-1.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="blog__item__text">
                            <ul>
                                <li><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> May 4,2019</li>
                                <li><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> 5</li>
                            </ul>
                            <h5><a href="#">Cooking tips make cooking simple</a></h5>
                            <p>Sed quia non numquam modi tempora indunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="blog__item">
                        <div class="blog__item__pic">
                            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/blog/blog-2.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="blog__item__text">
                            <ul>
                                <li><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> May 4,2019</li>
                                <li><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> 5</li>
                            </ul>
                            <h5><a href="#">6 ways to prepare breakfast for 30</a></h5>
                            <p>Sed quia non numquam modi tempora indunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="blog__item">
                        <div class="blog__item__pic">
                            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/blog/blog-3.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="blog__item__text">
                            <ul>
                                <li><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> May 4,2019</li>
                                <li><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> 5</li>
                            </ul>
                            <h5><a href="#">Visit the clean farm in the US</a></h5>
                            <p>Sed quia non numquam modi tempora indunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Blog Section End -->

   <?php get_footer();?>
```

although this image shows using same function

```
  <div class="hero__item set-bg" data-setbg="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('img/hero/banner.jpg'); ?>">
                        <div class="hero__text">
                            <span>FRUIT FRESH</span>
                            <h2>Vegetable <br />100% Organic</h2>
                            <p>Free Pickup and Delivery Available</p>
                            <a href="#" class="primary-btn">SHOP NOW</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

check screenshot for reference
[image]

the html outputs the image urls and the image exists in the folder

Comment: `data-setbg` is not a standard HTML attribute. It would not output a background image unless you had a script that was doing so. Are you using such a script?

Comment: yes ,...check  my code the hero image shows using same function ..i even tried this   <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <div class="categories__item set-bg" data-setbg="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()  ?>/img/categories/cat-2.jpg">
                            <h5><a href="#">Dried Fruit</a></h5>
                        </div>
                    </div> but that too didnt work

Comment: Why are you expecting to see a background image? That attribute does nothing without additional code.

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone

i go this sorted
i missed including some js files while enqueuing scripts
after i added those the image now shows using get_theme_file_uri or get_template_directory_uri() function within data-setbg